# how to have an image as background on html page

Tags: html, css

I have a sketch in pixels `1280 x 1024` and I want this sketch as background image of my html page and whatever else I show on the webpage will come on top of this image as div elements

I've seen this being done on many sites but when I put the image in the background it becomes so that I have o scroll the page horizontally.

Below is my css

```css
body #background img {
    left: 0;
    min-width: 1024px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">

<body>
 <div id="background"> 
  <img src="images/Sketch1.jpg">
 </div>
</body>
```

Update

putting image in background with no-repeat cuts the image down.

I've put an example here: http://jsbin.com/ekaxum/2

Comment: You can put an image as a background to the `BODY` element, or the `DIV#background` element.

Comment: Mike i'd say, super easy way to do this is to use jquery plugin.. for example this. http://srobbin.com/blog/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/ There are also many other plugins like this but, they mainly do the same thing. ( like this one as well ) Stretches image into fullscreen bg while keeping aspect ratio.

Answer (score 3):

```
body {
    background: url(url_here) no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

From the CSS 3 specification:

> ‘contain’: Scale the image, while preserving its intrinsic aspect ratio (if any), to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the background positioning area.

Comment: hmm but this cuts my image down and doesn't show it as a full

Comment: @Delan Azabani You should have guessed that the image was supposed to be stretched.

Comment: Why innovate in features if you aren't going to use them?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mike and welcome to Stackoveflow.

Just add the `height:100%;` property to the image's CSS style. The problem is that it's height is more than your actual window size so the *vertical* scrollbar appears. It changes the available window width and that's why you see the *horisontal* scrollbar.

Comment: this seems to work but the image looks distorted like its stretched awkwardly. Do I need to change the size of my image?

Comment: @Mike Well, such image resizes should be done in graphics editor. You can prepare a big background, say 1280x1024, and set it as the centered body background via CSS as it was advised earlier. A good approach here is to apply gradient to it's sides and bottom to a colour that will match the fixed `<body>` `background-color:;`. P.S. this may be useful: [css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image](http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/)